# How long should we wait to close a question based on "unclear what you are asking"?

Tags: discussion, subjective

How long should we wait for voting to close a question based on 'unclear what you are asking'?

Thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### You should not wait at all!

Things happen fast on Stack Overflow. We don't want question sitting around and getting answers while they are bad. That only encourages to ask bad questions and get answers anyway.

Vote to close (if you have the privilege). You can also leave a comment to the OP and tell him/her to improve the question.

If it gets closed and afterwards improved to be worthy of reopening then *mission accomplished*.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly why it's been renamed to 'On Hold' rather than 'Closed' - it gets put on-hold so improvements can be made.